# Sort array of objects by arbitrary list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given an array of objects like this:

```
objects = [
  { id: 'aaaa', description: 'foo' },
  { id: 'bbbb', description: 'bar' },
  { id: 'cccc', description: 'baz' }
];
```

And an array of strings like this:

```
order = [ 'bbbb', 'aaaa', 'cccc' ];
```

How would I sort the first array so that the id attribute matches the order of the second array?

Comment: What should happen when there is a missing element on any list?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this:

```
objects.sort(function(a, b){
    return order.indexOf(a.id) - order.indexOf(b.id)
});
```

Assuming the variables are like you declared them in the question, this should return:

```
[
    { id: 'bbbb', description: 'bar' },
    { id: 'aaaa', description: 'foo' },
    { id: 'cccc', description: 'baz' }
];
```

(It actually modifies the `objects` variable)

Comment: If there are elements in `objects` that aren't in the `orders` array they appear at the top. Is there a way to make those show up at the end of the list instead of the start?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle: Yea, you'd need to check both `indexOf` values for `-1`, and if they _are_ `-1` return `Number.MAX_VALUE` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need a way to translate the string into the position in the array, i.e. an index-of function for an array.

There is one in newer browsers, but to be backwards compatible you need to add it if it's not there:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(str) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) if (this[i] == str) return i;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Now you can sort the array by turning the string into an index:

```
objects.sort(function(x,y){ return order.indexOf(x.id) - order.indexOf(y.id); });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/u3CQW/

Answer (score 0):

### Use a mapping object for (almost) constant access time:

```js
/* Create a mapping object `orderIndex`:
{
  "bbbb": 0,
  "aaaa": 1,
  "cccc": 2
}
*/
const orderIndex = {}
order.forEach((value, index) => orderIndex[value] = index);

// Sort
objects.sort((a, b) => orderIndex[a.id] - orderIndex[b.id]);
```

```js
// data
const objects = [
  { id: 'aaaa', description: 'foo' },
  { id: 'bbbb', description: 'bar' },
  { id: 'cccc', description: 'baz' }
];
const order = [ 'bbbb', 'aaaa', 'cccc' ];

/* Create a mapping object `orderIndex`:
{
  "bbbb": 0,
  "aaaa": 1,
  "cccc": 2
}
*/
const orderIndex = {}
order.forEach((value, index) => orderIndex[value] = index);

// Sort
objects.sort((a, b) => orderIndex[a.id] - orderIndex[b.id]);

// Log
console.log('orderIndex:', orderIndex);
console.log('objects:', objects);
```