# Ant-design table handle custom sorter by data pre-determined

Tags: reactjs, antd

My ant-design table has column has a table like this:

```
    {
      title: 'State',
      dataIndex: 'state',
      key: 'state',
      sorter: (a, b) => a.state.localeCompare(b.state),
    },
```

Currently, my client don't want too sort state by alphabet string, they want to custome the result by the string pre-determined

```
Failed
Rejected
Canceled
Expired
Completed
```

How can I implement sorter with custom data as above?
Many thank

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by arbitrary list in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550847/sort-array-of-objects-by-arbitrary-list-in-javascript)

Comment: @Dien Can you provide a sandbox link for you issue?